# Why does "alive" come after "men" in "I found four injured men alive"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

> I found four injured men alive.

In this sentence, the adjective "alive" comes after the noun "men".

Why we have to use adjective "alive" after the noun, not before? because in adjective order, adjectives should come before the nouns.

Answer (score 1):

I think the structure is

Subject +verb+object+ adjective as objective complement.

> **I found four injured men alive**

it is similar to the structure

**He painted the house green**

**The Jury found him guilty**

Comment: Similarly, “I hope this letter finds you in good health.”

Answer (score 0):

It's a stylized use of "find".  You can "find [something] *to be* [some adjective]". The "to be" is optional.

> I **found** her (to be) **perfectly charming**
>
> I **found** the dinner (to be) **almost inedible**.
>
> I **found** the movie (to be) **exciting but implausible**.

In a similar way, in your example sentence, the writer *found* the injured men *to be* alive.

Comment: It could also be used as adjectively, in which case it would precede the noun, as in _I found four alive, injured men._

Comment: @MikeHarris “An alive person” is not correct, because [“alive” is postpositive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/alive)